# Rails i18n if I use unicorn and nginx as a application server doesnt work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, nginx, unicorn

When I run my app using default **WEBrick** server, and set locale from subdomain, i18n works perfectly to "en" and "ja".
However, when I use **Nginx and Unicorn** to run my app, i18n doesnt work like it does in WEBrick.

I write below codes to set locale from subdomain;

```
 def set_locale                                          
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale  
     if request.host.starts_with? "en."                    
      I18n.locale = "en"                                  
     else                                                  
      I18n.locale = "ja"                                  
     end                                                   
 end
```

What am I missing here?
My settings for unicorn and nginx are almost default except I changed the app name or the proxy_pass to app in nginx.conf.
Could anyone please teach me how to make i18n work?I'm stack all day....
Please excuse my poor English skill...
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at your `application.rb` file , you'll find a couple of settings for locale , like `config.i18n.default_locale = :en`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following line to your Nginx config inside your `location @app-name { }` or above your `proxy_pass` config:

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

Rails will be sent the `proxy_pass` setting as the host if this missing from your Nginx config.